# Removing Specific Line from Multiples files (.cpp /.h) in multiple directories

Tags: shell, cygwin

I have to send code to someone but before that I need to delete comments contains names of different developers who have worked on this project, I looked up online for results, I found a Shell script which is like:

```
foreach file '(*cpp)'
sed -i "/\b\(Dave\|Alex\)\b/d" $file > tt
mv tt $file
end
```

but it's not working, it does create a `tt` file but doesn't change the file, below is the output that I am getting:

```
$ ./Test.sh
./Test.sh: line 2: foreach: command not found
sed: no input files
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘tt’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
./Test.sh: line 5: end: command not found
```

I am running this script in the main directory where the code is present through Cygwin.

Comment: You shouldn't have developer names in source files in the first place. Revision control is for recording who did what.

Comment: True that , its a third revision so couldnt control it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me , though i had to change the extension and string couple of time

for file in $(ls *.cpp)

do
    sed '/Dave/d' $file > tt

mv tt $file

done

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks more like a `(t)csh` script than `(ba)sh`. Try this:

```
for f in *.cpp; do
    mv $f $f.bak
    grep -v '(Dave)|(Alex)' $f.bak > $f
done
```

Then send *.cpp (but not *.cpp.bak).

NOTE that this is a VERY CRUDE approach. If you have code in one of the files that
has a legitimate Dave or Alex substring in it, then such a line is going to get hosed too.

Comment: yes , i just found out foreach doesnt work in bash shell

Comment: so  i used file in and here >>mv tt $file>> i have moved temporary file into the original one so that i wouldnt have to pick